# ffmpeg: gif to mp4 - combining commands

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm converting a gif ( recorded at 1 frame per second) to an mp4 using these 3 commands:

```
ffmpeg -i input.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2,fps=10" temp.mp4
ffmpeg -i temp.mp4 -map 0:v -c:v copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb raw.h264
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -r 200 -i raw.h264 -c:v copy output.mp4
```

- 1st command converts gif to mp4 and increases fps to 10
- 2nd command converts mp4 to raw.h264
- 3rd command converts raw.h264 back to mp4 and increases the fps

Is there a way to combine some of these commands... So take the gif @1fps and output mp4 at 60fps?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2,setpts=PTS/45" -r 45 output.mp4` did the trick

Comment: You can answer your own question in a real answer. You can also mark it as "Worked for me". And others can rate it. And later one people can add other/better answers.

Comment: In addition it would be nice if you dissect a long blob of parameters like `-vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2,setpts=PTS/45"` and explain which part does what.